# Replacing equation with superscript in word

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

I want to replace all the [image]
into [image] inside my Word 2016. I tried changing all the equations into linear and used replace but it show the error ^' is not valid. My assumption is superscript style is not supported for searching. So, how can I process it? Thanks for reading and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about the arrow?

Comment: Yes, I need the prime ' to go outside the arrow.

Comment: Do you have many occurrences on your document?

Comment: Yes, I have been mistaken between those two for some pages, so I need to replace all of them.

Comment: Do you have Latex on the Equation tab (see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3vph.png))?

Comment: Yes, I do have. How can I process next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> used replace but it show the error ^' is not valid

You get the error because inputting a caret `^` while doing Find-Replace is not permitted. You must insert 2 carets `^^` to find 1. Based on the example you provided:

1. On the Equation tab, click on LaTeX
   [image: LaTeX button - MS Word Equation tab]
2. On your equation, click on the arrow on the right. Select "All Linear".

[image]
[image]

You will get this:

[image]

3. Copy from your equation this part: `\vec{p^^'}\left`. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, paste it on the "Find what" box. On the "Replace with" box, paste/enter the expression that must replace, in this case: `{\vec{p}}^^'\ \left`.
4. Click Replace All. Click on the arrow on the right of an equation, Select "All Professional".

Note that you will need to adapt the Find-Replace expressions based on your equations as they might be different.